# Autofill password that the user has saved for another site

Tags: web, passwords

I'll have users logging in on my site with credentials from another site where they already have an account. I'll use an API from the same site to validate the credentials in my end and authorize logins.
Since most users probably already have their credentials saved in their browser for the other site I wonder if there's a way my site can propose the same credentials for autofill on my site.

I think I've managed to make the browser propose the username from the other site. But that is not the same as using saved credentials in the browser I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be possible.  Auto-filling passwords from a third party site would be a huge security risk for those other sites.  It would make it trivial to steal a site's passwords by having the browser auto-fill the password and then auto-submit the form.